# Convert wallet from remote to local

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Is it possible to convert my wallet from remote node to local node, without having to move my coins?? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can simply switch to `Advanced mode`. This is done as follows. 1. Close the current wallet on the `Settings` page. | 2. Select `Advanced mode` as `Wallet mode` | 3. Reopen your wallet via the `Open a wallet from file` option. Let me know if this suggestion satisfactory answered your question.

Comment: You sir, are a genius... !! 

Thanks so much!!